# Binding bool value in ObservableCollection<Tuple<class, bool, bool>> to ListBox DataTemplate CheckBox crashes the program

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I'm getting my Users from API, and putting them to ObservableCollection of Tuple elements (need 2 bool values for CheckBox IsSelected fields that I use later)

```
private ObservableCollection<Tuple<UserDetails, bool, bool>> _users;

public ObservableCollection<Tuple<UserDetails, bool, bool>> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            OnPropertyRaised("Users");
        }
    }

public async Task GetUsers()
    {
        
        var tmp = await watchlistHelper.GetUsersAsync(); //API call
        if (tmp != null)
        {
            Users = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<UserDetails, bool, bool>>();
            foreach (UserDetails details in tmp.Content)
            {
                Users.Add(new Tuple<UserDetails, bool, bool>(details, false, false));
            }
        }
     }
```

When I'm trying to use it without binding to bool values like:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, ElementName=uc}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Item1.UserName }" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Everything displays properly (only UserName), but, when I try to bind it and use bool values, my program just crashes

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Users, ElementName=uc}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="write"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="manage"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2"  Text="{Binding Item1.UserName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <CheckBox Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding Item2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <CheckBox Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding Item3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
```

If I hardcode CheckBox values in xaml or dont use them - it works as intended, so it must be problem with bool in Tuple Binding to CheckBox, but I just can't wrap my head around what could cause it.

Comment: Have you tries value tuple `(UserDetails, bool, bool)`? Ot just regular class?

Comment: If you mean changing ObservableCollection<Tuple<UserDetails, bool, bool>> to ObservableCollection<(UserDetails, bool, bool)>    ---> it was how I intended to bind at first and it failed. Even binding to Item1 didn't work properly, so I changed it to Tuple<UserDetails, bool, bool> and it bind with Item1 no problem.

I already used this Tuple<> approach in my project, but it was Tuple<oneClass, anotherClass> as I remember and it worked perfectly